# Solving for optimal scaling matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, solver

I have numerous datasets from an official government agency that have perturbed data. However the same datasets have row and column totals that are from the original unperturbed data, so the rows and columns in a table do not add up to their respective totals - as the table below illustrates there is a difference when adding up the cells from the published totals (sum).

```
     X1  X2  X3  X4  SUM DIFF
Y1   27  45  54  31  165   -2
Y2   17  26  38  47  126   -2
Y3   44  42  40  50  178    1
Y4   46  16  22  15   98   -1
SUM 146 126 178  98
DIFF  0   0  -4  -1
```

I need to scale the perturbed data to get make the rows and columns add to the row and column totals (preferably in R). Which packages/functions would you suggest would make this quick and easy? In the example above the solution would be:

```
      X1    X2    X3    X4 
Y1  1.01  1.01  1.04  0.97
Y2  0.96  1.04  1.04  1.01
Y3  1.00  0.97  0.98  1.02
Y4  1.00  0.97  1.04  1.01
```

I've researched the question on stackoverflow and google and haven't been able to get a good guide on how this might be done efficiently in R.

Any suggestions very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This called `matrix balancing`. There are several ways to solve this, including:

- The well-known RAS algorithm
- A quadratic programming formulation
- An Entropy formulation [(link)](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2013/06/simple-data-set-to-show-equivalence-of.html)

I don't understand your data completely. I.e. the first row adds up to 156. The difference is not 2 but 9 (or -9). Another problem is that your known row sums and known column sums do not add up to the same number.

Anyway the RAS algorithm is easily coded in R. There is also a package [mipfp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mipfp/mipfp.pdf) that can help.

Comment: Thanks very much Erwin, that's exactly what i needed - just a nudge in the right direction. Apologies for the data error, i clearly punched the data in wrong.